# Intellij Idea errors on packages import in Scala Cross-platform project #27589

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, package, sbt, sbt-crossproject

I'm currently trying to implement a Scala cross-platform project using the sbt-crossproject plugin.

In the shared module i can't import Scala classes of other packages.
If i compile from sbt there are no errors and the project runs correctly but Idea still doesn't recognize classes from other packages.

The project repo is [here](https://github.com/VirusSpreadSimulator/PPS-22-Virsim/tree/develop) but you can reproduce it importing https://github.com/AndreaGiulianelli/scala-cross-project/ with sbt and opening the Prova2.scala source file.

Any suggest?

IDE version: 2022.1

Comment: Even after you `sbt compile`, intellij cannot recognize your import? And what is your IDE version?

Comment: Yes, even after sbt compile. IDE version 2022.1